# Webservice is an specification or architecture

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

My question is related to Webservice, is it a specification or architecture?
What I know that about the term Webservice, it is an architecture for communication between inter operable systems. It provides set of components like [WSDL(for service details), UDDI(for searching services), STUB, SKELETON, PROTOCOL (for content transfer) and Message (xml, json etc). 
Please correct if my assumptions are wrong?

Second, we have Soap and Rest web services. What does this means? Is there any changes in the web services architecture for both of these types?

Answer (score 0):

The term "Webservices" is a category of specifications; all what you mentioned belongs to these specifications. They enable you to implement your logical architecture, but they are not an architecture by themselves. There are other categories of specifications like RPCs like EJB and COM.

Please note that the terms UDDI, skeleton, proxy, stub, and protocol are general concepts for distributed systems and technical SOA not just for Webservices specifications.

For your second question. REST protocol is bound to the basic HTTP operations like GET, POST, PUT, DELETED (though many APIs are abusing GET for everything) and the desired operation is specified in the header not the body.

SOAP, on the other hand, specifies the operation in the message body (message envelop). The operation in the message can be anything as business requires, and it's specified on design time in the service definition which is the WSDL file.

REST loses some flexibility in the design for the sake of being light weight, since basic HTTP operations are mapped  to DB CRUD operarions.
SOAP provides more flexibility but it's heavier.

Comment: **The term "Webservices" is a category of specifications**, I think specifications are those which are released by Sun microsystem for Java in the name of JAX-RS and JAX-WS. And we have multiple implementations from different organisation like Apache, Sun etc.  A web service is a software system designed to support interoperable machine-to-machine interaction over a network. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service)

Comment: There are many ways of which a software system supports an interoperable machine-to-machine interactions over a network. What make them webservices is that they follow web standards whom usually released by organizations like W3C.

Comment: That's why I am saying that it is an design paradigm or architecture which is followed by programming language .

Comment: They're architectural enablers, by their adherence to open web specifications and standards.